# ERROR: Activation Context generation failed at the end of trace file, with NO previous ERROR

Tags: windows, com, side-by-side, mt

I have used `sxstrace.exe` and so far the tool has been very useful.

But now it says, at the end, that there is an error, with no previous errors in the trace...

How can I debug my problem?

```
=================
Begin Activation Context Generation.
Input Parameter:
    Flags = 0
    ProcessorArchitecture = Wow32
    CultureFallBacks = en-US;en
    ManifestPath = C:\XXXXX\testregfree\Desktop Agent\CtxtRun.exe
    AssemblyDirectory = C:\XXXXX\testregfree\Desktop Agent\
    Application Config File = 
-----------------
INFO: Parsing Manifest File C:\XXXXX\testregfree\Desktop Agent\CtxtRun.exe.
    INFO: Manifest Definition Identity is (null).
    INFO: Reference: XsScrSite,processorArchitecture="x86",type="win32",version="1.0.0.0"
    INFO: Reference: XsWrkMng2,processorArchitecture="x86",type="win32",version="1.0.0.0"
    INFO: Reference: Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls,language="&#x2a;",processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df",type="win32",version="6.0.0.0"
INFO: Resolving reference XsScrSite,processorArchitecture="x86",type="win32",version="1.0.0.0".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\XXXXX\testregfree\Desktop Agent\XsScrSite.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\XXXXX\testregfree\Desktop Agent\XsScrSite.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Manifest found at C:\XXXXX\testregfree\Desktop Agent\XsScrSite.MANIFEST.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
INFO: Resolving reference XsScrSite.mui,language="&#x2a;",processorArchitecture="x86",type="win32",version="1.0.0.0".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
INFO: Resolving reference XsWrkMng2,processorArchitecture="x86",type="win32",version="1.0.0.0".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\XXXXX\testregfree\Desktop Agent\XsWrkMng2.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\XXXXX\testregfree\Desktop Agent\XsWrkMng2.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Manifest found at C:\XXXXX\testregfree\Desktop Agent\XsWrkMng2.MANIFEST.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
INFO: Resolving reference XsWrkMng2.mui,language="&#x2a;",processorArchitecture="x86",type="win32",version="1.0.0.0".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls,language="&#x2a;",processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df",type="win32",version="6.0.0.0".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls\6.0.0.0_en-US_6595b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls\6.0.0.0_en_6595b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls\6.0.0.0__6595b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls\6.0.0.0_en-US_6595b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls\6.0.0.0_en_6595b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: Auto Servicing Policy redirected assembly version.
                INFO: Post policy assembly identity is Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df",type="win32",version="6.0.19041.1110".
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.19041.1110_none_a8625c1886757984.manifest.
                INFO: Manifest found at C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.19041.1110_none_a8625c1886757984.manifest.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui,language="&#x2a;",processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df",type="win32",version="6.0.19041.1110".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui\6.0.19041.1110_en-US_6595b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui\6.0.19041.1110_en_6595b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui\6.0.19041.1110_en-US_6595b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui\6.0.19041.1110_en_6595b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
INFO: Parsing Manifest File C:\XXXXX\testregfree\Desktop Agent\XsScrSite.MANIFEST.
    INFO: Manifest Definition Identity is XsScrSite,processorArchitecture="x86",type="win32",version="1.0.0.0".
INFO: Parsing Manifest File C:\XXXXX\testregfree\Desktop Agent\XsWrkMng2.MANIFEST.
    INFO: Manifest Definition Identity is XsWrkMng2,processorArchitecture="x86",type="win32",version="1.0.0.0".
ERROR: Activation Context generation failed.
End Activation Context Generation.
```

UPDATE: result of `mt -inputresource:CtxtRun.exe -out:extracted.manifest`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"
          manifestVersion="1.0">
    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="XsScrSite"
                              type="win32"
                              version="1.0.0.0"
                              processorArchitecture="x86"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="XsWrkMng2"
                              type="win32"
                              version="1.0.0.0"
                              processorArchitecture="x86"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity type="win32"
                              name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
                              version="6.0.0.0"
                              processorArchitecture="x86"
                              publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
                              language="*"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker"
                                         uiAccess="false"/>
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
    <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <windowsSettings>
            <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
        </windowsSettings>
    </application>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Probably something in these .manifest files it did not like, unrelated to assembly resolution.  We can't see them.  Look in the Application event log for a detailed error message.

Comment: @HansPassant The two "dependency" manifest were generated by `mt.exe`. The executable's manifest was indeed authored. I added it to the question. There is zero error message in the Application event log (at the corresonding approx. time)

Comment: Its tedious but in this kind of situation I would normally add/remove things from the manifest by trial and error until I find the entry (or entries) which cause the problem. You may find using a separate manifest file easier for that, rather than embedded. Beware that if you edit the manifest file you need to touch the timestamp of the EXE or the manifest changes won't be noticed.

Comment: That's the trick. Multiple add/remove and trial/error. But the whole thing IS an UTTER MESS (in my humble opinion)